# Angularfire2 get single document without listener

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm using angularfire2 v6 and angular 11. I'm simply trying to get a single document from the users collection based on their email. I don't want to use `valueChanges()` or `snapshotChanges()` as the user object won't be updated, and if it is, I don't care to get realtime updates. I just want to get the data once when the user navigates to their profile. I've seen that you should be able to use `get()` instead of the aforementioned methods, but I can't get anything to work correctly.

Doing this works fine:

```js
let query = (this.firestore.collection('users', ref => ref.where('email', '==', res.email)).valueChanges());
// subscribe to changes
query.subscribe(queriedItems => {
  this.item = queriedItems[0];
  this.firstName = this.item.firstname;
  this.lastName = this.item.lastname;
  this.email = this.item.email;
  this.role = this.item.role;
  this.lead = !!this.item.lead;
});
```

But again, doesn't `valueChanges()` by nature keep listening for updates? I don't want to do that. And replacing `.valueChanges()` with `.get()` means I can't subscribe, and using `toPromise().then()` seems to just return junk and not the actual document.

Comment: I was trying to figure out the same thing. Both of these were helpful: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47549001/how-to-use-get-method-to-retrieve-all-collection-in-angularfire2/47550869
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197455/firestore-get-all-documents-in-a-collection-returns-an-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't figure out how to make the `get()` work at all, but I did find a workaround by setting it to a subscription, then unsubscribing once you get the data.

```
this.fireAuth.currentUser.then((res) => {

  let query = (this.firestore.collection('users', ref => ref.where('email', '==', res.email)).valueChanges());
  // subscribe to changes
  this.profileSubscription = query.subscribe(queriedItems => {
    this.item = queriedItems[0];
    this.firstName = this.item.firstname;
    this.lastName = this.item.lastname;
    this.email = this.item.email;
    this.role = this.item.role;
    this.lead = !!this.item.lead;

    //Unsubscribe here if you don't want an active listener to show changes
    this.profileSubscription.unsubscribe();
  });

});
```